# Running a website/web application that analyzes big data

Tags: web, web-applications, data-analysis, bigdata

Hello i have this website where the server has in its database 2-3 GB of data and i want the user to run a query to get the data and analyze it (for example the user can put age>15) and then press the button that says cluster to do clustering in that data , then the user sees that with libraries like d3.js.

how to do it ? Can i link Hadoop or something like that with php /nodejs ? 
Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I think that your size of data is not relevant to use as BigData Stack.

Maybe configure your RDMS to perform well with your requests could solve your problem.

In size of GB it will not give you a nice response in Hadoop... In your case, if you need small latency I suggest Cassndra or maybe Redis for the request.

Don't use Hadoop for GB.

Comment: yes but how can i apply clustering and data analysis ?

Comment: You don't need Big Data for Data Analysis, there is a tons of solutions sklearn for Python R has a tons of libs. That works really fine for analytics.

Answer (score 0):

You should use RDBMS, which will provide better results, if configured right. RDBMSs are easy to be intergrated into web applications.

Hadoop is a distirbuted file system, and should be used for way more than GBs of data, otherwise it will just slow you down.

Answer (score 0):

We need more information.

Depends on the data store, type of data we can go with different options

Option 1:
Relational data base can store Terabytes of data in clustered platform with replication set either though log shipping / streaming can handle the GB of storage . Then comes the analysis . It depends on how the data is stored. MS SQL server can easily handle Tera bytes of data and apply analytics engine on top. This is the option if we are storing the data in denormalised way and ACID is a key factor. Transaction aware.

option 2
If the data is received and stored in document model (JSON) and consistency and replication is factor rather than availability . MongoDB is the best in market which we can set in primary , secondary setup . The javascript interpreter in mongo shell will help data handling very efficiently.

Option 3

If consistency and ACID is not a constraint and availability and data is stored as key value . The best bet is Cassandra. Built a better has and Terabytes of data will be an ease as it replicates across nodes with in DC or cross DC. Better hash key definition is a major factor for sharding here